# DisplayTag indexing ?

Tags: jsp, displaytag, stripes

How do I get the index location in DisplayTag lib ?

I've been trying the following but appreantly it's not right:

```
    <display:table name="${actionBean.templateItems}" id="templateItems" defaultsort="">
      <display:column title="Product" property="name"/>
        <stripes:hidden name="templateItems[%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}].id" value="${templateItems.id}"/>
     </display:table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

displaytag uses the id attribute of the table tag, and appends "_rowNum" to this attribute, to define another attribute containing the current row number.

So, the attribute, in your case, is named `templateItems_rowNum`. And as any page scope attribute, you access it using `${templateItems_rowNum}`:

```
<stripes:hidden name="templateItems[${templateItems_rowNum - 1}].id" 
                value="${templateItems.id}" />
```

You shouldn't use a plural form (`templateItems`) to refer to a single object. It makes things very confusing. The current element should thus be named `templateItem`.